# How do you center the Color Scale as per Title on Plotly?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Question in the title. I have a colour scale of a graph, but I want to align the scale to the centre / middle of the Scale Title. Right now, it's aligned to the left in default. I tried the colorbar_xanchor and colorbar_x as per the Docs, but they didn't help. Is the center alignment possible?

I am attaching the current scale below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

---

No, this is not possible at the moment (but I hope someone proves me wrong).

---

#### Some details:

It appears to not be possible to center the coloraxis on the title. There doesn't even seem to be a functional workaround. I've tried to center the title on the coloraxis insead through adjusting the attributes of both the colorbar itself:

```
layout.coloraxis.ColorBar({
    'bgcolor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    'bordercolor': '#444',
    'borderwidth': 0,
    'exponentformat': 'B',
    'len': 1,
    'lenmode': 'fraction',
    'minexponent': 3,
    'nticks': 0,
    'outlinecolor': '#444',
    'outlinewidth': 0,
    'separatethousands': False,
    'showexponent': 'all',
    'showticklabels': True,
    'thickness': 30,
    'thicknessmode': 'pixels',
    'tickfont': {'color': '#2a3f5f', 'family': '"Open Sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif', 'size': 12},
    'tickformat': '',
    'ticklabeloverflow': 'hide past div',
    'ticklabelposition': 'outside',
    'tickmode': 'auto',
    'tickprefix': '',
    'ticks': '',
    'ticksuffix': '',
    'title': {'font': {'color': '#2a3f5f', 'family': '"Open Sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif', 'size': 14},
              'side': 'bottom',
              'text': 'another title'},
    'x': 1.5,
    'xanchor': 'center',
    'xpad': 10,
    'y': 0.5,
    'yanchor': 'middle',
    'ypad': 10
})
```

And the title:

```
layout.coloraxis.colorbar.Title({
    'font': {'color': '#2a3f5f', 'family': '"Open Sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif', 'size': 14},
    'side': 'bottom',
    'text': 'another title'
})
```

And not matter what, the start of the title text seems to be anchored on the left of the colorbar:

[image]

I've also tried adding spaces for a manual adjustmen, but without any luck:

fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.text = 'another title' + '  '*(len(fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.text))

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
data = px.data.gapminder()

data_canada = data[data.country == 'Canada']
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop',
             hover_data=['lifeExp', 'gdpPercap'], color='lifeExp',
             labels={'pop':'population of Canada'}, height=400)

# fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.text = 'another title' + '.'*(len(fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.text)*10)
# fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.text = 'how to center the colorbar on the title'
# fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.xanchor = 'left'
fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.text = 'another title' + '  '*(len(fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.text))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's too sad then. Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed post. I do hope it comes through sometime in the future